# invoking winrs from python subprocess fails with path with quotes

Tags: python, path, escaping, quotes

I'm trying to use `subprocess.Popen()` to execute a Python script on a remote computer. This works OK for most cases, but if the path to Python contains spaces, it fails. Surrounding the path with double quotes doesn't help, no matter how I escape them--`winrs` seems to escape them with `\"` and the path is not interpreted correctly on the remote.

This gives errors like `'\'\\"C:\\progam files\\py\\python.exe\\"\' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file'`.

I've tried every combination of flags to `Popen` I can think of, tried escaping the quotes with `^`,`\`,`"`,`` ` `` to no avail.

Any help greatly appreciated. The code:

```
#lots of variations of this, all fail...
cmd = '"C:\\my py\\python.exe" --version'

def _winrs_spaces(cmd,host,user,pw,port=8080):
    winrs = 'winrs'
    args = [winrs,
           '-nop',
            '-r:http://%s:%s' % (host, port),
            '-u:%s\\%s' % (host,user),
            '-p:%s' % pw,
            cmd]

    proc = subprocess.Popen(args,stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE,shell=True)
    stdoutData,stderrData = proc.communicate()
    ret = proc.returncode

    if stdoutData:
        print(stdoutData)

    if stderrData:
        print(stderrData)

    if ret:
        raise IOError('_spaces failed')

    return stdoutData
```

Comment: I should have made it clear--I'm using Popen on Windows to execute WINRS, which executes python.exe on the remote Windows host.